# Pallet cluster-spec and "lein pallet up"

Tags: clojure, pallet

I'm using pallet 0.8 and have several group-specs defined

```
(def group1 (group-spec ...))
(def group2 (group-spec ...))
;...etc
```

They are combibed to create several machines which will be my "test environment". There should be several such environments with different sets of group specs. Now i'm using groups in my pallet.clj:

```
(defproject my-project
  :groups [group1 group2))
```

This is working fine, and when i run "lein pallet up" i have my nodes up. I also would like to add some common parameters to all groups inside specific "environment". For this i tried to use `cluster-spec`

```
(def my-cluster
  (cluster-spec "my-cluster" :groups [group1, group2])
   ;...some other parameters)
```

Is this intended usage of `cluster-spec`? How do i use it with `defproject`? Or how do i merge `cluster-spec` map into `pallet-project-map`?